# Evaluate series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^{n-1}}}{1-x^{2^n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Determine the value of
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^{n-1}}}{1-x^{2^n}}$$
>   or $$\frac{x}{1-x^2}+\frac{x^2}{1-x^4}+\frac{x^4}{1-x^8}+\cdots$$
>   for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The answer is $\dfrac{x}{1-x}$ for $x\in(0,1)$. To prove this, notice
$$\frac{x}{1-x^2}=x+x^3+x^5+\cdots$$
$$\frac{x^2}{1-x^4}=x^2+x^6+x^{10}+\cdots$$
$$\cdots$$
Add them all and get the answer. Unfortunately, I havn't got a **direct** method to calculate it. Appreciate for your help!

Comment: A silly comment but do you consider
$$\frac{x}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+1}=\frac{x^3+x}{x^4-1}\cdot\frac{x^4+1}{x^4+1}=\frac{x^7+x^3+x^5+x}{x^8-1}\cdots$$
and induction as a simplification?

Comment: @epimorphic Very bad idea of an edit, sorry to say...

Comment: @Did `\limits` really has no place inline, including in titles. For one thing it breaks the layout on the front page.

Comment: @epimorphic Says who? The extra vertical space is minimal and at least we get a readable formula. :-)

Comment: @Did See the end of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827) and also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32826). The fact that you have to force it speaks for itself. The formula isn't unreadable without it.

Comment: @epimorphic Hmmm... "Otherwise, one is virtually assured of wrecking the appearance of the paragraph where the formula appears." What is wrecked exactly on the present page? On the contrary, one gets a nice looking formula of moderate dimensions instead of its ugly alternative... (But thanks for the links.)

Comment: @Did That's your opinion; you don't like text-mode limits for sums and I don't like the extra space that appears on the _front_ page. Note that your new edit bumped a question without any activity for nearly a day to the front page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^{n-1}}}{1-x^{2^n}}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^{n-1}}.(1-x^{2^{n-1}})}{(1-x^{2^n}).(1-x^{2^{n-1}})}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^{n-1}}-x^{2^{n}}}{(1-x^{2^n}).(1-x^{2^{n-1}})}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-(1-x^{2^{n-1}})+1-x^{2^{n}}}{(1-x^{2^n}).(1-x^{2^{n-1}})}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{1-x^{2^{n-1}}}-\frac{1}{1-x^{2^n}})
$$
Now consider upto $k$ terms then this can be written as

(second term of $nth$ expression cancelled by first term of $(n+1)th$ expression) ,
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1-x^{2^k}}
$$
For $k\to\infty$ and $x\in(0,1)$, 
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}-1
$$
Which is equal to 
$$
\frac{x}{1-x}
$$

Answer (score 7):

As soon as $|x|<1$ we have
$$ \frac{x^{2^{n-1}}}{1-x^{2^n}} = x^{2^{n-1}}+x^{3\cdot 2^{n-1}}+x^{5\cdot 2^{n-1}}+\ldots \tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{2^{n-1}}}{1-x^{2^n}} = \sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{h\geq 0} x^{(2h+1) 2^m} = \sum_{n\geq 1} x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}\tag{2} $$
since every positive integer can be represented in a unique way as the product between a power of two and an odd integer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in(0,1)$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. I shall prove that there is a natural number $p$ such that$$n\geqslant p\Longrightarrow\left|\frac x{1-x}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^{2^{k-1}}}{1-x^{2^x}}\right|<\varepsilon.$$Take $p'\in\mathbb N$ such that $\left|\frac x{1-x}-(x+x^2+\cdots+x^{p'})\right|<\varepsilon$. Take $p\in\mathbb N$ such that, when you express any element of $\{1,2,\ldots,p'\}$ as the product of an odd number with a power of $2$, then the exponent of that power of $2$ is always smaller than or equal to $p$. Then $$n\geqslant p\Longrightarrow x+x^2+\cdots+x^{p'}\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^{2^{k-1}}}{1-x^{2^x}}<x+x^2+x^3+\cdots=\frac x{1-x}$$and therefore$$\left|\frac x{1-x}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^{2^{k-1}}}{1-x^{2^x}}\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Adding term by term: 
$$S=\frac{x(1+x^2)+x^2}{1-x^4}+\frac{x^2}{1-x^8}+...=$$
$$\frac{(x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^4)+x^4}{1-x^8}+\frac{x^8}{1-x^{16}}+...=$$
$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n}{1-x^{2\cdot \infty}}=$$
$$\frac{x}{1-x}$$

because $0<x<1$.